# Is this a memory leak in my AS3 AIR desktop app, or should I not worry about it?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm running this on a 1 second timer:

```
trace(String(System.totalMemory));
```

It shows that my app's memory is increasing about 1mb every 5mins, even when it's dormant.

In testing, when I run

```
System.gc(); System.gc();
```

in the same function that runs the System.totalMemory every second 1 second, the memory drops right down and stays down around 8mb. However, if I run

```
System.gc(); System.gc();
```

just once, the memory drops down to 8mb, but then continues to go up at the previous pace.

Why would my app be increasing it's memory usage when it's sitting dormant, and is this something to worry about, or does that fact that System.gc(); System.gc(); drops the memory right down mean that I don't have memory leaks and that I should just let the garbage collector take care of things?

Thank you.

Comment: Most likely the latter, as your app's footprint doesn't increase from those 8MB. However, it's possible that there is an activity that takes more resources than it should running in your app's background, generating lots of events or other disposable objects. Also check if your app produces some heavier objects instead of renewing them, like `BitmapData`s, these consume some chunks of memory that you effectively don't leak but may reuse.

Comment: Thank you Vesper. I think I was misleading in y question. If I run System.gc(); system.gc(); just once ie not every second, the memory drops down to 8mb, but then continues to go up at the previous pace.

Comment: This doesn't change much here. Your app's un-GC'd footprint does not grow, hence no memory leak. I wonder if there are enough enterframe events in 5 minutes to amass 1MB of heap to be GC'd... at least 300*30=9000, that many `Event` objects might occupy a megabyte.

Comment: Some garbage collector wait until an specific amount of memory is occupied. So when this limit is 200MB you have to wait 16 hours until GC will reduce the memory automatically. However some GCs set this limit to quarter of RAM so when you have 16GB the limit will be 4GB or 6 days of waiting before GC occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a memory leak, your memory would be increasing for no intended reason and not be fully reduced by the garbage collector.

This would be a memory leak:

```
Memory usage: 8 MB
Memory usage: 12 MB
Garbage collection.
Memory usage: 9 MB
Memory usage: 14 MB
Garbage collection.
Memory usage: 10 MB
Memory usage: 16 MB
```

And so on, as you can see from the example, the base memory used after garbage collection completes is increasing. In your case the base memory is 8 MB and it doesn't increase so there is no leak.

A leak happens when you consume memory in a way that cannot be collected by the garbage collector when it is no longer needed.